# Jquery, hide radio button label if not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio group with three buttons. Is it possible to hide JUST the radio label if the radio button is not selected. The code I have so far is;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
    label = self.next(),
    label_text = label.text();

    label.remove();
    self.iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line',
      radioClass: 'iradio_line',
      insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
    });
  });
});
```

The HTML code is:

```
<input type="radio" name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" value="2">
<label>Fixed</label>

<input name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" type="radio" value="1" checked>
<label>Failed</label>

<input type="radio" name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" value="0" id="Action1_2">
<label>Passed</label>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks you for your time.

Comment: a jsFiddle is always a nice thing :)

Comment: are you using some custom jquery plugin ??

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is this possibly what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/qupeft3p/1/

Comment: sounds like bad usability to me. How's the user supposed to know which one to select if they want to change it, when the labels are hidden?

Comment: @atrljoe Sorry I have not gotback to you sooner, Attending a funeral yesterday. I have looked at the JSFIDDLE and this is what I am looking for. But when I use your code in my script only the first row of radio buttons work. My script dynamically generates the rows. Lets say I have tree rows, each with three radio button. If I click one on the second or third row, only the top row changes. How would I make each rows work? Again, thanks for your time. My own http://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/4cnwq480/

Comment: You would need some sort of way to differentiate the containers that hold the radio buttons. Like so https://jsfiddle.net/qupeft3p/2/

Comment: @atrljoe, Many thanks, this work perfectly.